# Qt Sensors Qml compile error

Tags: android, qt, compilation, qml

I am looking at the example application for the Qt Sensors that comes with qt and I've complied it on windows with no errors, but as soon as I try to put it onto my android I get this compile error.

```
10:41:51: Running steps for project qmlqtsensors...
10:41:51: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
10:41:51: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'first'.
10:41:52: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
10:41:52: Removing directory C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_x86\examples\sensors\build-qmlqtsensors-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build
10:41:52: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" INSTALL_ROOT="C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_x86\examples\sensors\build-qmlqtsensors-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build" install
copy /y "libqmlqtsensors.so" "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_x86\examples\sensors\build-qmlqtsensors-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build\libs\armeabi-v7a\libqmlqtsensors.so"
        1 file(s) copied.
The full path of C:C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_x86\examples\sensors\build-qmlqtsensors-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_armv7\examples\qtsensors\qmlqtsensors is too long.
makefile:873: recipe for target 'install_app' failed
mingw32-make: *** [install_app] Error 1
10:41:53: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\Tools\mingw48_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project qmlqtsensors (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.1))
When executing step 'Copy application data'
10:41:53: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

I've looked on google with no avail. Can anyone help me with this problem please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error or at least one of them is because the path to your file qmlqtsensors is too long.

```
The full path of C:C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_x86\examples\sensors\build-qmlqtsensors-Android_for_armeabi_v7a_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_2_1-Release\android-build\Qt\Qt5.2.1\5.2.1\android_armv7\examples\qtsensors\qmlqtsensors is too long.
```

Try to compile and run your project at a different location with a shorter path.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and this is the error i get now :-1: error: No rule to make target '..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Android_Bundle\android-ndk-r9c\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include\bits\c++config.h', needed by 'main.obj'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

I get the error on this example (and had the same on previous examples some while ago).

My problem turned out to be that when the Makefile is generated, it generates 'wrong' code.  It generates stuff like:
      mkdir C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)/........

which is fine if $(INSTALL_ROOT) evaluates to a relative path but in fact it resolved to an absolute path, that is:
      mkdir C:C:/Qt/.......

So simply edited the Makefile replacing all occurrences of 'C:$(INSTALL_ROOT)' with '$(INSTALL_ROOT)'.  It worked for me and hopefully you too.